# how to run random sampling a million times from a csv

Tags: python, random, iteration, sampling

I have a big csv looks like this

```
claim score
yes   1
yes   1
no    1
no    1
yes   1
...   1
...   1
...   1
```

score is all the same number, i need to run a lots times of random sampling for size say (1000). Then calculate the mean percentage of yes counts

the code looks like this:

```
#imports
import random
import numpy

TotalYes = 0
csvFile = numpy.genfromtxt("/nas/home/twu/wind/output_1.csv",delimiter=",",dtype=None)
for j in range(1,10001):
    #csv format : claim (Yes/No), value
    #read in your csv file and store in array
    #initialize random number generator
    random.seed()

#create RandomSample array
RandSamples=[]
samplesize = 1000
#Fill RandomSample array with 10000 random samples from cvs array
for i in range(1,1001):
    #for row in csvFile:
    #get a random index within csvFile[]. random num range is 0 to csv array length
    randIndex=random.randint(0,len(csvFile))
    print randIndex
    RandSamples.append(csvFile[randIndex:randIndex+1,:])
#RandSamples1=numpy.asarray(RandSamples)
#get number of 'yes' from RandomSample array
RandYesSample=[]
for i in range(0,1001):

    # check to see if current record is Yes claim or no
    if RandSamples[i:i+1,:1] == "yes":
        #yes, copy value to yes array
        RandYesSample.append (RandSamples[i:i+1,:1])

#get percent of yes in RandomSample array
PercYes = float(len(RandYesSample)) / 1000
TotalYes = TotalYes + PercYes

TotalYes = float(TotalYes) / 10000

print TotalYes
```

The error I had is:

```
if RandSamples[i:i+1,:1] == "yes":...TypeError: list indices must be
integers, not tuple
```

I cannot get it working. can somebody help?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: i run a multiple times already. it keep saying too much indices

Comment: @alice what the full error shown? please post it

Comment: RandSamples.append(csvFile[randIndex:randIndex+1,:])    Index error: Too much indices

Comment: if RandSamples[i:i+1,:1] == "yes":...TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: @alice remove the comma , its the problem, check my answer

Comment: Don't initialize the random number generator 10000 times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with slicing lists, it should be like `[start:end:step]` but you are putting a comma that should be removed:

```
csvFile[randIndex:randIndex+1,:]
```

should be

```
csvFile[randIndex]
```

same in:

```
if RandSamples[i] == "yes":
```

and:

```
RandYesSample.append (RandSamples[i])
```

Comment: but if i want access the the first column where equal to yes, is it RandSamples[i:i+1}? is this to access the rows?but then how to access the first column?

Comment: `csvFile[i][0]` for claim, `csvFile[i][1]`  fore score

Comment: i changed to    for i in range(1,1001):
  if RandSamples[i][0] == "yes":
   #yes, copy value to yes array
   RandYesSample.append (RandSamples[i]) it says list index out of range

Comment: even when i change to for i in range(i, len(RandSamples)), it still give me error saying index error:index out of boiunds

Comment: change all ranges to `range(0,1000)`

Comment: @alice if this answer helped you to fix your first error, please consider to mark it as accepted

Comment: the problem is randomeyessamples list did not pick up the yes field

Comment: the randomyessample list did not pick up the yes field. for i in range(0,1000):
  #for row in csvFile:
 
  randIndex=random.randint(0,len(csvFile))
  ##print randIndex
  RandSamples.append(csvFile[randIndex:randIndex+1])
  #print csvFile[randIndex:randIndex+1]
 #RandSamples1=numpy.asarray(RandSamples)
 #get number of 'yes' from RandomSample array
 # check to see if current record is Yes claim or no
 #print RandSamples
 for i in range(0,1000):
  for row in RandSamples[i][0]:
   if value in row:
   #if row[0] == "yes":
    RandYesSample.append (row)
   #yes, copy value to yes array